# uninitialized constant Timeout::Error at Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

This is what I see in my Heroku logs:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 44765`
app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rackup)
app[web.1]: NameError: uninitialized constant Timeout::Error
app[web.1]: Did you mean?  KeyError
app[web.1]:                IOError
app[web.1]:                Errno
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:164:in `<class:Resolv>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
app[web.1]:   /app/sixnines.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   /app/config.ru:23:in `require_relative'
app[web.1]:   /app/config.ru:23:in `block in <main>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
app[web.1]:   /app/config.ru:in `new'
app[web.1]:   /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:273:in `start'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:148:in `start'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rackup:22:in `load'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rackup:22:in `<top (required)>'
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I tried everything and can't really understand why `timeout` is not found. Any hints? This is the source: https://github.com/yegor256/sixnines

Comment: Is there a chance that `timeout` gem have broken Ruby's `Timeout` module where `Timeout::Error` defined?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk I suspect that's exactly what is happening. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try to change gem 'timeout' to gem 'timeout-extensions'. Won't help - throw it out. You need no 0.0.1 gem with 9 stars, Luke :)

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk that was it, replaced it with `timeout-extensions` and the problem disappeared. Thanks! Feel free to post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, gem name is [timeout-extensions](https://github.com/celluloid/timeout-extensions). RubyGems has allowed to publish it also as [timeout](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=timeout) for unknown reasons.

Therefore when included in `Gemfile` as `timeout`, it brakes Ruby's native `timeout` module which defines `Timeout::Error`.

So, line in `Gemfile` should be

```
gem 'timeout-extensions'
```

instead of

```
gem 'timeout'
```